# Calling a .php file

Tags: php

I am what you call a developer with basic PHP scriptings, i have not yet developed complicated scripting so please bear with me.

I am working with a Pie Chart. This php script i found in the net creates a PNG File once it is called.

Example if you accessed it directly like ..

> www.url.com/generate.php

This will create a generate.png Image of the Pie Chart

I want to pass values in to as to feed the SP to be used.

Example i like to use SP_contacts i would pass it like

> www.url.com/generate.php?foo='SP_contacts'

it will then call the SP then after the query it will generate the Image.

then I would like to call the generated image and **ECHO** it in the **HTML page**.

i will have my **Index.php** page to handle the **ECHO**, now how will I call this **generate.php** inside my **Index.php**

I am not sure how to make it work as I havent read any PHP Books or were trained to use PHP. I am just a go develop and learn guy and hopes that the internet is there for me. haha. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular problem you would do best to separate your main page from your code.

Find all the variables that you're going to have to pass to the generate function, and then on the main page you use it as if it were an image:

`<img src="/generate.php?var=val&var2=val2&etc" />`

Comment: Sir, how do i show generate.php as an image. i did as you suggested. i saw in my directory that the image was generated but it did not show in my main page.

Comment: BTW. generate.php isnt a function. or is iT? it doesnt end with a return or some sort

Comment: When you say "i saw in my directory that the image was generated" do you mean that there is another file after the generation process? Your generate.php is creating a file named [yourimagename]? Then you have to reference this image within the <img>-Tag of the answer above.

Comment: As TRD said.  I assumed that generate.php was returning or displaying an image, not storing it in a file.  If thats the case, then my answer is incorrect.

Comment: its not returning or displaying an image but it stores in the same folder as the .php file. e.g. generate.png  .. how do i return it as an image instead?

Comment: if it's calling a function like "imagepng($filename);" or "imagejpeg($filename);" you could remove the variable and it would return the image.  If you go that route, you'll also need to output appropriate headers (e.g. image/png or image/jpeg).